# cxf - how to create a REST NO soap endpoint on top of another endpoint

Tags: rest, cxf

I have one endpoint already that is soap and now would like to create a non-soap interface that delivers the body of the POST into my methods (and would like simple GETs to work where I can just return a body of xml).  I ran into this example

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs/basic/src/main/java/demo/jaxrs/server/Server.java?view=markup

but those methods don't seem to exist on the latest version.  This was geared towards JSON I believe but looks like it might work for my purposes.  Is this even possible?  In addition, I already have one endpoint like so and want to add this new one as well...

```
    JaxWsServerFactoryBean svrFactory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
    svrFactory.setServiceClass(EnrollmentService.class);
    svrFactory.setAddress("http://0.0.0.0:9000/enrollment");
    svrFactory.setServiceBean(enrollmentSvc);

    Server svr = svrFactory.create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [CXF Rest](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html)

I think what you need is a jax rs service. It support POST and several json providers are also available.

Comment: I had run into that, I tried using the JaxRsServerFactoryBean instead of the JaxWsServerFactoryBean to no avail, and then the sample rest-http-binding it does not use JaxRsServerFactoryBean so I am very confused and still don't have a working example yet with JaxRs...I have something with JaxWs but not sure that is the right thing yet...still need to packet sniff it to make sure.